# Getting today datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

today=datetime.today().strftime('%Y,%m,%d')

start=dt.date(2017,9,22)
end = dt.date(today)
```

I want to get today timestamp in python, I tried this with error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-e64689f2e644> in <module>
      4 
      5 start=dt.date(2017,9,22)
----> 6 end = dt.date(today)
      7 
      8 s=dt.date(2020,9,16)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: you have not defined 'dt' in line 3 of your code . Also since you have imported datetime from datetime your line 4 doesnt work .
just use import datetime and this below line should work 
start = datetime.date(2017,9,22)

Comment: Please mark this question as answered. Enough people have given the  right solutions, its only right thing to do - to mark an answer accepted. If not please mention what you were expecting and how the solution was not right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To get the date for today you can use `datetime.date.today()`.

```
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2017, 9, 22)
end = datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: Why can't we use below snnipet? { import datetime
print(datetime.date.today()) }

Comment: what's your error?

Comment: ok, i got it , appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you have not defined 'dt' in line 3 of your code .
Also since you have imported datetime from datetime your line 4 doesnt work . just use import datetime and this below line should work start = datetime.date(2017,9,22)

I would sugges same answer as suggested by @monkut
change your code to below

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
start=datetime.date(2017,9,22)
end = today
```

Comment: ok, i got it , appreciated!